# E-Mail sent from PHP mail() going to spam folder (SPF is set, header shows pass)

Tags: php, email, spam, spf

I've been trying for days to get mail to send to peoples' inboxes instead of being routed to spam folders and I'm coming up against a major wall.

I've searched and search, on here and other forums, and I've tried every fix I could find. None of the solutions listed in similar questions on here seem to solve this issue for me.

As far as I can tell it seems like it should be fine, but nothing gets through to the inbox. If anyone can help shed some light on the situation it would slow my current rate of hair-loss!

Here's the raw source output for an example message:

```
Delivered-To: (myhome@emailaddress)
Received: by 10.52.188.161 with SMTP id gb1csp138113vdc;
        Tue, 23 Jul 2013 12:03:55 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.14.7.2 with SMTP id 2mr34154813eeo.145.1374606233813;
        Tue, 23 Jul 2013 12:03:53 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <www-data@mydomain.com>
Received: from mydomain.com ([my.server.ip.address])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id l7si29937488eey.240.2013.07.23.12.03.53
        for <myhome@emailaddress>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Tue, 23 Jul 2013 12:03:53 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of www-data@mydomain.com designates my.server.ip.address as permitted sender) client-ip=my.server.ip.address;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of www-data@mydomain.com designates my.server.ip.address as permitted sender) smtp.mail=www-data@mydomain.com
Received: from mydomain.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by mydomain.com (8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.4) with ESMTP id r6NJ3qBd032597
    for <myhome@address>; Tue, 23 Jul 2013 14:03:52 -0500
Received: (from www-data@localhost)
    by mydomain.com (8.14.3/8.14.3/Submit) id r6NJ3pxE032595;
    Tue, 23 Jul 2013 14:03:51 -0500
Date: Tue, 23 Jul 2013 14:03:51 -0500
Message-Id: <201307231903.r6NJ3pxE032595@mydomain.com>
To: myhome@address
Subject: Test email
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:functions.php
From: My Website <noreply@mydomain.com>
X-Mailer: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze15
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<html><body><center><h3>This is an email!</h3></center></body></html>
```

Comment: The SPF makes the email get passed by the server, but it doesn't do much for the client. Make sure it's not the recipient's mail client doing the spam chucking.

Comment: Maybe your server is blacklisted? Do you share server space and what email clients / addresses are used?

Comment: Can you get hold of the headers for a copy of your mail that's gone into someone's spam folder? I think SpamAssassin, for one, adds headers to show which flags any given email has triggered, so it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. It is specifically the recipient system doing the spam-chucking -- the email is being sent to a Google Apps account (same as GMail). I've checked to see if the domain is blacklisted and it passes every testing tool I've used. The source I pasted in the original post shows all the headers I can see (it's taken from the spam folder that the e-mail was dumped in)